# Cannot connect to Exchange PowerShell to run scripts remotely using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, smtpclient

I need to run PowerShell script on our exchange server. I've enabled PS-Remoting and WinRM-quickconfig on both my local machine and SMTP server. When i try to connect I receive the error below.

*Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.*

Here is my connection code below
NOTE: I can connect to SMTP server with this user account using RDP

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //CREATE SECURE STRING PASSWORD
            string pwd = "MyPasswordAsAString";
            char[] cpwd = pwd.ToCharArray();
            SecureString pass = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in cpwd)
            pass.AppendChar(c);
            //CREATE PS CREDENTIAL
            PSCredential Credential = new PSCredential("Domain\\Username", pass);
            //RESOURCE URI
            string shell = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";

            //ADDRESS OF SMTP SERVER
            var target = new Uri("HTTP://FULLYQUALIFIEDDOMAINNAME");

            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(target, shell, Credential );

            //CREATE RUNSPACE
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

            //OPEN CONNECTION
            runspace.Open();
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            { 
                ps.Runspace = runspace;
                ps.AddScript("Get-Service"); 
                var results = ps.Invoke();
                // Do something with result ... 
            }  
            runspace.Close();




            //AFTER FILE IS CREATED THROUGH POWERSHELL READ IT WITH EXCELL
            DataTable PF2 = processFile(@"C:\inetpub\Clients\MLK\confRooms-permissions.xlsx", "xlsx");
            importData(PF2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out!
Changed the variable target to Uri type and  address to service i added port/wsman